# Using HuggingFace embeddings with Langchain install locally

Tags: embedding, langchain, huggingface

HuggingFace is downloading embeddings models and not using them via API. Everytime i execute the app, it downloads the model.

I tried using other class like HuggingFaceInferenceAPIEmbeddings but it does the same as HuggingFaceEmbeddings, it downloads the model and it does not use it via API (without the need of installing it). Can someone tell me how can i use embeddings from huggingface via online?